# Xdebug configuration

Tags: php, netbeans, wamp, xdebug, netbeans-plugins

I am new to php and I need to use Xdebug with netbeans for a remote school purpose.

My php's version is 7.3.21 and I am using it with Wamp. Netbeans is on 11.1 version.

I installed last updates for wamp and xdebug, and the problem is when i run debugger in netbeans, xdebug doesn't load and keeps this status running :
[image]

So I investigated and xdebug seems installed as you can see here (from click on wamp -> php -> configuration) :

[image]

and here (from click on wamp -> php -> extensions) :

[image]

Everything seems ok, but still doesn't work. So I check on https://xdebug.org/wizard with phpinfo() function, pasted the return in the textarea and here's the status :

[image]

I check everything and here is my php.ini file :

[image]

In this context, using the debugger shows me infos on a html page as you can see on following image but I can't inspect my variables in netbeans because of the "waiting for connection (netbeans-xdebug)...

[image]

I tried to use "localhost" instead of my IPv4 address, and "ext" instead of "zend_ext" but the html page doesn't provide me anymore informations.

Moreover the weird thing is that when I copy-paste a php -i result in the textarea from https://xdebug.org/wizard, it tells me that xdebug isn't installed .....

[image]

I checked and tried many posts' solutions from stackoverflow, but nothing is working, I don't know what to do more, so if any of you guys could help me it would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Edit: Thank you Arsen for the answer, I tried both of your suggestions and followed the upgrade guide but none is working . Here is my php.ini file which I modified that much that I can't even get back to the base configuration..

Should uninstall wamp and install it again ?

I have a 5.6.40 php version and the preinstalled xdebug 2.5 version is working in netbeans.
The problem is that I will have to modify an app written with php 7 and use phpUnit / phpDocumentor / codeSniffer. Do you think that working with e 5.6.40 php version would be fine ?

Again, I am new to php / wamp and all the related stuff, sorry if my questions are "stupid".

[image]

Comment: no, PHP 5.6 and PHP 7 have major differences. Have you changed netbeans to listen on port 9003? Also `remote_autostart` does not exist anymore. Read the upgrade guide again and carefully!

Comment: If all else fails, I recommend to enable [the log option](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#log) and see what the xdebug log is saying.

Comment: Hello, finally I could do whatever, nothing made Xdebug 3 work. So I simply went back to a 2.x version and everything's working fine. I would have liked to make it work but as I didn't have much time to work on my project I had to chose the simpliest way to solve my problem. Thank you anyways Arsen.

Comment: Did you have a looksie into the xdebug log? Just out of curiosity :)

Answer (score 4):

XDebug 3 is still pretty new and it appears your xdebug-configuration in your ini-file is still using the config names for XDebug 2. Luckily, XDebug provides a [upgrade guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide), which you should adjust your config according to.

My first guess is that you are using the wrong port, because XDebug 3 is using port `9003` by default and you are expecting port `9000` in NetBeans.

So you can either:

1. Listen on port 9003 in NetBeans or
2. Set `xdebug.client_port` to 9000 in your ini-file. (Rather than `xdebug.remote_port`, see the upgrade guide Ilinked above)

Keep in mind that you should go through the upgrade guide for all your configuration settings to ensure that XDebug is actually doing what you want it to.

Comment: Thanks Arsen, i edited my post, if anyone can help.